# Jasper-Reports - Pagefitting Subreport is split when included in Main Report

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports, subreport

I am currently designing a report, that is supposed to use multiple subreports in the Detail Section of a main Report. I am at the very start and up to now have only left the Detail 1 and Page Footer Band for my main report, using Page X of Y in the Footer, and my first subreport in Detail 1.

I am using the A4 Landscape Page format for both reports.
My Subreport is currently containing a Title Band and a Detail Band.

Both reports use "select GetDate() as test" as their main Dataset, so that it's a single line, keeping the detail section from printing multiple times.

Each Element of my Subreport is using their own Dataset (2 lists, 1 Bar Graph)

The problem I have is that even though my Subreport fits my Page, as inis printed on single page when using preview, when i include it on my main report, it suddenly splits the Title and Details Band (I am not using "Title on a new Page") and puts the content on 2 pages.

Is there a way to force each Subreport to fill the exact space on the main report, as it does on it's own?

Edit 1: Additional Problem
The Preview of the Main Report doesnt Change when I modify the Subreport, it always shows an old Version of the Sub-Report

Comment: Can you share screenshot/PDF output of your report?

Comment: I'd like to but somehow printing the report into a PDF somehow breaks the Report and makes it not look anything like the preview. I think it might be the sizing of A4.
Like the Full Report is not showing any content and the subreport is somehow printed it as horizontal so it's trimmed on one side and has a weird black rectangle on the bottom.

Comment: Even though i figured out how to export it correctly, I cannot share the files because of company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-Compiling the Subreport actually proved successfull as it updated what the main report showed, so it now fit the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two solution:

1. You can set `splitType = Stech` in band.
2. set `RunToBottom = true` flag in subReport